# JTree selection without generating event

Tags: java, swing, selection, listener, jtree

I have a JTree, a JTable and a JList which displays the same set of objects, but in different order and with different information.  If an item is selected from one of the Component, I want to select the same object on the other two Components (meaning they should be highlighted).  Naturally I monitor the selection events with a Listener.  Here is the problem, when a Component retrieves the selected object, I'll have to make sure the object is selected on the other Components by calling selection methods on them.  This, will then notify the selection listeners on the other two components.  But each of those events will in turn call selection events on components other than itself, causing an infinite loop going among the three Components.

I see one solution is to use a boolean flag, and make the listeners not propagate the selection if the flag is set.  However, this seems cumbersome and not elegant.  Is there a way to simply tell JTree, JTable and JList to make the selection but not fire any events (as oppose to fire an event and then catching and stopping it with a boolean flag)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SharedModelDemo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#SharedModelDemo).  I think it does what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes.  Thank You.  This works.  It'll be some work to make a model which works for Tree, Table and List at the same time, but this seems better than keeping booleans around.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a flag indicating whether it's user changes or internal changes but yu can also remove listeners before selection call and add them after to prevent events firing.

Comment: I don't really like this approach.  What if there are several Listeners, wouldn't I be doing more work that needed?  I am not looking for a work around.  I am looking for a properly design.